# jquery on vs click methods

Tags: jquery

I know that the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, is supposed to replace `live`, `delegate` etc. But is there any point in using it on places where you're currently using the [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event? For example on elements that are not dynamically generated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's not specifically worth replacing `click()`, as in the jQuery source it converts all the 'shortcut' event handlers (like `click()`, `keyup()` etc.) to `on("event", fn)` anyway.

Comment: From the docs: `There are shorthand methods for some events such as .click() that can be used to attach or trigger event handlers. For a complete list of shorthand methods, see the events category`. So the answer would be no, just as @Rory is saying I think.

Comment: Just as you didn't use `.bind("click")` instead of `.click()` before, you don't need to use `.on("click")` instead of `.click()` now.

Comment: But the shorthand method .click() will call .on() and then will attach the event handler at the root level and the bubbling phase will traverse all the structure from the element to the root. With .on() directly, you can attach the click event listener to the immediate parent node and this will reduce the bubbling phase but in case of click event, I think it will be a very very small improvment.

Comment: Forget it, it will be bind to the element itself in the DOM. Brain fart!! :(