# targeting a link with a class inside of an <li> with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click

I have a structure that looks like this...

```
<ul class="flex-direction-nav">
   <li>
    <a class="prev" href="#">Previous</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="next" href="#">Next</a>
  </li>
```

Using JQuery, how would I target those links so I can do something when the user clicks it.

Thanks

EDIT: Maybe I should note that the text is not visible, but rather indented -9999px and the background image is in it's place. I tried a couple of these but I'm not getting the alert that i'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.flex-direction-nav a').on('click', function(){
    // A link was clicked
})
```

[A simple Fiddle demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/N77mF/)

Comment: Just note that .click function is a shortcut for .bind("click", handler), as well as for .on("click", handler) as of jQuery 1.7. Also See -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/8601512/297641

Comment: `$('.flex-direction-nav a').on('click', function(){
         alert("THIS IS AN ALERT!");
});`

But I'm not getting an alert... Could it be because there is no text in the link, but rather the text is indented -9999px and there is a background image...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.flex-direction-nav').find('a').click(function(){
    // Do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
$('.flex-direction-nav li a').click (function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
        //do prev
        alert('prev clicked');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
        //do next
        alert('next clicked');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/23VGG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".flex-direction-nav .prev").click(function(){
    //do stuff for prev button here
});
$(".flex-direction-nav .next").click(function(){
    //do stuff for next button here
});
```

Comment: This isn't working... The text is being indented off screen, and the background image is an arrow. This is also for a slider if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".prev").click(function() {
  alert("You clicked prev!");
});


$(".next").click(function() {
  alert("You clicked next!");
});
```

..

Or of course:

```
$(".flex-direction-nav a").click(function() {
   alert("You clicked a link in the navigation ul.");
});
```

Comment: This isn't working... The text is being indented off screen, and the background image is an arrow. This is also for a slider if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
//first link
$("ul.flex-direction-nav a.prev").click(function(e){
//code to be executed
});

//second link
$("ul.flex-direction-nav a.next").click(function(e){
//code to be executed
});
```

where "e" parameter is the event object http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/
I would recomend to replace the href value form "#" to "javascript:void(0)", to avoid triggering the scrollbars

Comment: This isn't working...

The text is being indented off screen, and the background image is an arrow. This is also for a slider if that makes any difference.