# Different between on('click') and .click()?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery on vs click methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601482/jquery-on-vs-click-methods)

I have noticed some are saying to use "on" in the latest jQuery, but what is the difference and is it true I should use it?

```
$("#dataTable td").on("click", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});

$("#dataTable td").click(function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None. Look [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L1021) in the jQuery source. The .click() function is basically just an alias for .on('click'), the relevant code being this:

```
return arguments.length > 0 ?
    this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
    this.trigger( name );
```

Although .click() is more concise I would recommend using [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if you want to be consistent, as it always was intended to unify event handling introduced with .bind, .live and the shorthand methods like .click.