# jQuery event-handlers

Tags: click, jquery

I have been searching around without finding an satisfying answer. What is the difference between the 2 following event-handlers.

```
$('#div').on('click', function(){
    //do something
});
```

and

```
$('#div').click(function(){
    //do something
});
```

I know that in the `$('#div').on('click', function()`, you can send in more div or class-selectors in addition to `'click'`, but is that it?

I'd love to hear what else separates them, and if there are times where one is better to use than the other.

Thanks

Comment: `click()` is the shorthand for `on('click')`. That's it (in your use-case).

Comment: There are no differences.

Here is another post identical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click

Comment: @Zenith Btw, yesterday you answered one of my other post - turned out you were right- the fiddle you provided me did work :) but you deleted your answer or something? Anyway - thanks!

Comment: Isn't `click()` a shorthand for `.bind('click')` which is quite different than `.on('click')`?

Comment: @PhilippM No. `.bind` have been deprecated in favor for `.on`.

Comment: @PhilippM: The `click` documentation was updated to *"This method is a shortcut for `.on('click', handler)`"*

Comment: Duplicate of this one as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8601482/218196.

Comment: @Nilzone- Don't worry - I found the other answer nicer (more flexible) so I deleted and upvoted that instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) can be used to bind event to elements that is not present at the page load, but may appear later. There are other benefits also.