# When a Div class is clicked, alert it's inner content's Div Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child

How do i even put these, let me try. In the following sets of codes, i want to click 'parentclass' and have an alert value of 'child1' and when i click the class below it which is 'Parent 2' have an alert fire with a value of 'child2'

So this must alert the content of that class only and not the entire class.

Here's some Javascript in Jquery.

```
var childclass = $('.childclass').html();
$('.parentclass').click(function(e) {
    alert (childclass)
});
$('.childclass').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

And HTML

```
<a href="" onClick="return false">
    <div class='parentclass'>
       Parent 1
    <div style="display:none" class="childclass">child1</div>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="" onClick="return false">
    <div class='parentclass'>
      Parent 2
    <div style="display:none" class="childclass">child2</div>
 </div>
</a>
```

Comment: So you want just the first text node of the children within each parent?

Comment: so clicking the childclass div is supposed to do nothing, but clicking the parentclass div alerts with the child class's content?

Comment: not the first text, the entire content of the child inside the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line `var childclass = $('.childclass').html();` doesnt make sense as it doesn't know which element in particular you mean. The result of that will just be `child1child2` which is just a concatenation of the `.html()` of all the elements with class `childclass`. This is obviously not what you want.

Therefore you should dynamically find the child with a class of `childclass` upon receiving the click event.

```
$('.parentclass').click(function(e) {
    alert($(this).find('.childclass').html())
});
```

Also, you should know that your child class event handler is useless as we don't care if the event gets propogated downwards. If you DID care, then your `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` should be in the event handler of the parent class.

Answer (score 3):

You need to fetch the html of the clicked parent element within the click handler

```
$('.parentclass').click(function (e) {
    alert($(this).find('.childclass').html())
});
$('.childclass').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6Kj7x/)

Answer (score 1):

Several ways you can go about this.

First, if your HTML will not be dynamic (elements already exist when page loads), then you can select elements by the parent class name and assign click event as so:

```
$('.parentclass').click(function(e) {
    //  the first variable here is selecting the inner elements having class 'childclass'
    //  keep in mind, if more than one child having that class is present within this parent, it will select all of them
    var child = $(this).find('.childclass');
    //  here we alert the text of the inner child found
    //      if it is more than one, you will have undesired results. you may want to specify `.first()`
    alert(child.text())
})
```

For newer jQuery you can also use `$('.parentclass').on('click', function(e) {`.

---

If you expect any pieces of `parentclass` to be dynamic, then you'll want to delegate the event based on either a static parent to the parents or `document`.  This can be like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.parentclass', function(e) {
    alert($(this).find('.childclass').text())
})
```

Or, if you have a static (already there when page loads) wrapping element, give it an ID like `parentClassWrapper' and assign the click event dynamically as:

```
$('#parentClassWrapper').on('click', '.parentclass', function(e) {
    alert($(this).find('.childclass').text())
})
```

---

Some helpful links:

- [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com)
- [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [**`.click()`**](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [**`.on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [Some info on Event Delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/)
- [jquery on vs click methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601482/jquery-on-vs-click-methods)
- [jQuery .on('click') vs. .click() and .delegate('click')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296530/jquery-onclick-vs-click-and-delegateclick)
- [jquery .live('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944293/jquery-liveclick-vs-click)

Answer (score 0):

I made several adjustments to your html that are worth noting. There's no need for the `<a>` tag. Don't use inline js - `onlick` in your html. Note that I wrapped the text inside of the div in the `<a>` tag instead. This markup is more semantic. Also, move your styles to css rather than in the html.

```
  <div class="parent">
    <a>Parent 1</a>
    <a class="child">child of parent 1 contents</a>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <a>Parent 2</a>
    <a class="child">child of parent 2 contents</a>
 </div>
```

css:

```
.parent > .child { /* good practice: only select an immediate child of the parent */
  display: none;
}
```

The other answers here are using `find()` to select the child, but I recommend `children()` instead. For example, if you had additional nested `.child`s, `find()` will select them all, but `children()` will only select direct `.child`s of the parent, so it is better in this case.  I also recommend using the console for debugging rather than `alert`.

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/AwOvowO/2/edit)

```
$('.parent').click(function() {
  var $child = $(this).children('.child');
  var cls = $child.attr('class');
  console.log(cls);
  $child.show(); //added so that you can click the child
});

$('.child').click(function() {
  var html = $(this).html();
  console.log(html);
  //if you just want the text, use this instead:
  var text = $(this).text();
  console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: i put the anchor tag just to change the cursor when it's hovered over this divs since they are not buttons.

Comment: That is not the correct solution. You either should change the whole div to an anchor, or use css `cursor: pointer` on the div. @Eustatia